# How to fire an ad pixel and redirect?

Tags: ads, google-ads-api, adsense, pixel, facebook-ads-api

Let's say I have a page "X" that is not owned by me but I am trying to direct paid traffic to (from Facebook ads). I can't set tracking pixel there since I don't control the source. I am thinking to create a proxy that loads the pixel and then redirects to the page 'X' and link to this proxy site instead.

I can't find any proxy services that already enable this. I am wondering if it's possible to do this or if there any caveats to this.

Comment: If you can't have a pixel on the landing page. The only thing you can do is to have a click tracker.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to do this with the Facebook Pixel.

You could choose to open the link in a new tab by using `target='_blank'` on the anchor, and then firing the pixel even in the source page.

The alternative is to use some interstitial page where you fire the event and then do the redirect, but you'll have to make sure the pixel has finished loading before you redirect.